# How to prove non-existence of positive equilibrium if I get a boundary equilibrium when lamda=0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\begin{array}{l}
{u_1}(m - {u_1} - b{v_1}) = 0\\
{u_2}(m - {u_2} - b{v_2}) = 0\\
 - {v_1} + \lambda [ - d{v_1} + d{v_2} + {v_1}(m - c{u_1} - {v_1})] = 0\\
{v_1} + \lambda [d{v_1} - d{v_2} + {v_2}(m - c{u_2} - {v_2})] = 0
\end{array}$$

If I want to use implicit function theorem to abtain a mapping from lamda to u(lamda), v(lamda), I don't know how to prove that there is no positive equilibrium point.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.